# Creating links inside a List item's 'description' column

Tags: list

May I know if it is possible to creating links (on the current item 'description' column) to other item in the same SharePoint List? (Assuming that there are two column in this List - column 1 is 'Title', column 2 is 'description'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything stopping you from typing in a URL in the description field. I seem to recall that Sharepoint is smart enough to return it as a clickable hyperlink on rendering.

Comment: +1 So good that SharePoint is smart enough to return it as a click-able hyperlink on rendering but may I know if SharePoint is also smart enough to identify keyword that corresponding to another Item in the same list and auto-create hyperlink pointing to that item?

Comment: I have created a new question (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/auto-create-hyperlink-pointing-to-another-item-in-the-same-list-possible) based on my comment.