# Auto-create hyperlink pointing to another Item in the same list - Possible?

Tags: list, hyperlink

May I know if SharePoint 2007 is able to identify keyword that corresponding to another Item in the same list and auto-create hyperlink pointing to this item's description column. (Assuming that there are two column in this List - column 1 is 'Title', column 2 is 'description')

**More Details**:
Let me elaborate further - I have a scenario where currently, there is a List that contain two keyword and their description. The 1st keyword is "jQuery" and its description is "jQuery is a cross-browser JavaScript library designed to simplify the client-side scripting of HTML". The 2nd keyword is "HTML" and its description is "Hypertext Markup Language (HTML) is the predominant markup language for web pages.".

So, SharePoint auto-create a link for the word 'HTML' (which point to the keyword 'HTML') inside the 'JQuery' keyword's description because the 'HTML' is one of the keyword that is found in the List.

If in the future, someone added a new keyword 'Javascript' inside the list, SharePoint will also auto-create the link pointing to this keyword for the 'jQuery' keyword as its description contain the word 'JavaScript'.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a lookup column in the list that points to another field in the same list.  This would automatically create a hyperlink to that item.

Comment: +1 nice, clean, simple

Comment: Added more details.